# Request gets aborted when sending a large photo in the body

Tags: java, spring-boot, nginx, server, request

So I have a problem with my API, that handles a request bigger than 1mb locally (I am sending an image in the body). It needs to send an appropriate response message when a client sends a picture larger than 2mb.

But the problem lays on the server, it throws an 413 error that is referencing "Nginx 413 Request Entity Too Large". And I tried fixing it with adding the

```
client_max_body_size
```

and bumping it to a bigger size, it removed the response, but now postman is loading the request for a long period and then it just aborts the request.

Has anyone had experience with this kind of problem, and what could be the solution. Could the proxy connection times be the solution of the problem?

Comment: Yes, if your request is getting aborted after a while, especially sensiblle defaults like 60, 120 or 300 seconds, it's probably a timeout somewhere. Could be on one of your proxies, or some other intermediate server.

Comment: Yeah I just checked and it gets aborted after 60 seconds. So what could be the solution of the problem? If I manage to change the timeout time, then the client should wait a couple of minutes to get a error message that will inform him that the image size is too large?

Comment: If your backend is willing to accept images of that size, the best solution is to fix proxy settings to allow large requests. If not, you could check the `Content-Length` header (not always reliable) or you could terminate the request (just stop reading and respond with an appropriate error code) once the maximum size is exceeded.

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways I can think of :

1. Encrypt your image in the client and send it as a stream. In the backend, you can decrypt and use it
2. Ask the client to upload the image to an external storage eg. S3, from where your back-end can read

Comment: What does encryption have to do with anything?

Comment: with encryption, we are simply trying to secure the data in transit

Comment: Well duh, but what does it have to do with the question?